# Read SimpleXmlElement object

Tags: php, cakephp, xml-parsing

I have the following xml to be parsed.

```
Array
(
 [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [rel] => http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other
                [address] => xyz@gmail.com
                [primary] => true
            )

    )

[1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [rel] => http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other
                [address] => abc@gmail.com
                [primary] => true
            )

    )
)
```

I have this above xml and I need to get only adress from this xml.

```
foreach ($result as $title) {
   $email[$count++]=$title->attributes()->address->__toString; 
}
debug($email);
```

The result is this. But I want only address . need some help.

```
Array
(
[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
    )

[1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
    )
)
```

Comment: this might help `$email[$count++]=(string)$title->attributes()->address;`

Comment: yup ..that works...can you add that as answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see : http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php

> > **Return Values**
> >
> > Returns a SimpleXMLElement object that can be iterated over to loop through the attributes on the tag.

the solution is to cast the value into string,
for example :

```
$email[$count++]=(string)$title->attributes()->address;
```

Or iterate the return value will work as well

eg:

```
foreach($title->attributes() as $key => $val)
{
  if ($key == 'address') $email[$count++] = $val;
}
```